# не отправляется форма в django после валидации js

Tags: javascript, html, django, form, валидация

имею js скрипт, вроде работает

```
let PhoneReg = /^(\+7|7|8)?[\s\-]?\(?[489][0-9]{2}\)?[\s\-]?[0-9]{3}[\s\-]?[0-9]{2}[\s\-]?[0-9]{2}$/;

let inp = document.querySelector("#id_phoneNumber")
let PhoneSpan = document.querySelector("#id_phoneNumberFeedback")

document.querySelector('.btn').onclick = function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!validate(PhoneReg, inp.value)) {
        notValid(inp, PhoneSpan, "Введите правильный номер");
    }else {
        valid(inp, PhoneSpan, "");
    }
    return true;
};

function validate(regex, inp) {
    return regex.test(inp);
}
function notValid(inp, el, mess) {
    inp.classList.add('is-invalid');
    el.innerHTML = mess;
}
function valid(inp, el, mess) {
    inp.classList.remove('is-invalid');
    // inp.classList.add('is-valid');
}
```

код формы в html

```
        <form action="{% url 'add_feedback' vacancy.pk %}" method="post">
           {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 mt-3">
                    {{ form.phoneNumber }}
                <div id="id_phoneNumberFeedback" class="invalid-feedback">
                    Please provide a valid city.
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-2">Отправить</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: "имею js скрипт, вроде работает" - так работает или нет?

Comment: скрипт работает, а форма не отправляется

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` имеет смысл тогда, когда нам не нужно отправлять форму, не так ли?

Comment: Все верно, сработало. Спасибо